# Generate instances from another module in always @(posedge clk)

Tags: verilog

```
module save_random (clk,in,out);

parameter size=10;
parameter k=10;
 input clk;
 input [k-1:0] in;

 output [k-1:0]out;
 wire [size:0] cout;

 genvar i;     
generate

for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1)
begin: level1
always@(posedge clk) begin

 random ins(clk,in[i],cout[i+1]);//generte 10 instances from module random to save it //in registers
 end
end

endgenerate
assign cout[0]=in[0];
assign out=cout[k];
endmodule
```

I have a task to write synthesis code that generates 10 random values and save each value in register or Dflipflop or something like this.

The first `(save_random)` module that generates 10 instances from module random `(the 2nd one)` and `connected ..`, but it still has **error when I am using clk input with generate i..**

```
module random(clk,d,cout);
 
 parameter size=8;
 input [size-1:0] d;    
 input clk;

output  [size-1:0]cout;
reg  [size-1:0]cout;
integer i;

always@(posedge clk)
begin
     cout<=d;
end 
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot instantiate modules inside an `always` block. As you have a module `random` which is a register of size `size`, you only need to instantiate that module inside your generate if you need more than one:

```
genvar i;     
generate begin
  for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) begin: level1
    random ins(clk,in[i],cout[i+1]);
  end
end
```

However, note that `in[i]` and `cout[i+1]` are not an 8-bit values. So if you want to use the full 8-bit register, you need to declare them to be 10 (or 11 for `cout`) 8-bit vectors:

```
input [7:0] in [9:0];
wire [7:0] cout [10:0];
```

This tutorial might give you a better idea how generate blocks work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CKfP4n9ge0